# How to know the model of the computer from Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, device-name

I am unable to find my computer model name. I have Ubuntu 12.04. I tried HardInfo and System Monitor, but could not find it. I know this is a noob question, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The easy way is to make a text file to search in between do -

```
sudo lshw | grep product >file
gedit file
```

Everything will be displayed clearly.The first line will your product name.

You can also view release date , product name, baseband manufacture by followings-

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date
sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name
sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer
```

hpe its all clear now.

Comment: Also you can use `-t, --type TYPE`: Only  display  the  entries of type TYPE: `sudo dmidecode -t system`.

Comment: Old but it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: In case you don't want to save output to a file, you can just omit the `>file` part and contents will be displayed in your terminal's buffer:
`sudo lshw | grep product`

Answer (score 12):

Try the below command on terminal on get the exact model name,

```
sudo dmidecode | less | grep Version | sed -n '2p'
```

Try this command to display your pc's model name with some information,

```
sudo dmidecode | less | grep Version
```

Try this for product name,

```
 sudo dmidecode | less | grep "Product Name"
```

Comment: Since I wanted the Product name, the command that worked was 
sudo dmidecode | less | grep "Product Name"
dmidecode worked.

Comment: It does not show product name..

Comment: sudo dmidecode | less | grep "Product Name" save the world! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a GUI Application to display some hardware and software information about the computer.

```
sudo apt-get install sysinfo
```

Comment: or lshw via teminal

Comment: lshw doesn't display pc model name.

Answer (score 1):

`dmidecode` is the favorite, you can get your needs using:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep Version
```

For example my output is:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of these solutions worked for me. If you just run `man dmidecode` it tells you how to get specific system information strings, such as the model name. I tried this on three different laptop models:

`sudo dmidecode -s system-family`

and it replied with my family model name, which is what I wanted.