# How do I get the computer's SNID number from Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, oem, reinstalling, hardware-certification

The hardware product [file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386927/how-to-know-the-model-of-the-computer-from-ubuntu) has some codes but its not clearly telling me if any is a SNID.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the serial number ID by enter the following in a terminal:

```
sudo dmidecode -s string
```

where string is replaced by any of a number of parameters...

bios-vendor
bios-version
bios-release-date
system-manufacturer
system-product-name
system-version
system-serial-number
system-uuid
baseboard-manufacturer
baseboard-product-name
baseboard-version
baseboard-serial-number
baseboard-asset-tag
chassis-manufacturer
chassis-type
chassis-version
chassis-serial-number
chassis-asset-tag

So in your example, to find the SNID you would use:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-serial-number
```

[reference](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-serial-number-of-lenovo-laptop-from-linux/)