integrated graphics not detected after fitting new LCD, how can I use nvidia card to run the screen or detect the integrated graphics again?
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz × 8
Graphics Card Nvidia TU106 GeForce RTX 2060 (rev a1)
I broke the screen on my Medion Deputy P10 laptop and replaced it with an LCD from them. During the replacement I switched the laptop on to check it was working but the connector for the LCD was not seated correctly so the screen did not work but the external monitor did. Now the built in display does not work using Ubuntu 20.04 but it does if I boot windows. I also fitted a different SSD and installed ubuntu 24.04 and the built in display still does not work. The display does show the medion splash screen on boot and if I go into recovery shell the built in display is working. After some more time looking at it I can see the the display is actually on, just extremely dim so I wonder if it just the backlight not working.
xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

lspci | grep VGA:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] (rev a1)

lshw -c video:
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:148 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b4000000-b407ffff

I think the problem is that the intel integrated graphics are no longer detected, this is the same on ubuntu as well as windows. Windows seems to be able to use the Nvidia card to run the laptop display but I can't see a way to do this on ubuntu. In nvidia-settings I can see the display but I have no 'prime profiles' tab to make the Nvidia card run the built in display as suggested in the answers to similar questions. I have also tried updating the linux kernal to 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64 and the nvidia driver to 550.54.14. I also tried using the nouveaux driver and that got a bit further and displayed the ubuntu splash screen but then just goes to a cursor in the top left of the screen.
Would really appreciate if someone can help me either find the intel integrated hardware or get the Nvidia hardware to run the built in display.
Thanks in advance.
edit:
lshw | grep product
product: Deputy P10 (ML-210008 30029468)
product: K15C
product: M471A1K43CB1-CTD
product: M471A1K43CB1-CTD
product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz
product: 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
product: TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060]
product: TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
product: TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller
product: xHCI Host Controller
product: xHCI Host Controller
product: TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller
product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
product: Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
product: Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
product: xHCI Host Controller
product: HighSpeed Hub
product: HHKB Professional
product: 2.4G Wireless Mouse
product: USB2.0-CRW
product: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
product: xHCI Host Controller
product: Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
product: Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
product: Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
product: Comet Lake HECI Controller
product: Intel Corporation
product: Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9
product: E12 NVMe Controller
product: E12S-512G-PHISON-SSD-B27B
product: Intel Corporation
product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
product: Comet Lake LPC Controller
product: Comet Lake PCH cAVS
product: Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
product: Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
product: PnP device PNP0c02
product: PnP device PNP0c02
product: PnP device INT3f0d
product: PnP device PNP0303
product: PnP device PNP0c02
product: PnP device PNP0c02
product: PnP device PNP0c02
product: PnP device PNP0c02
product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
edit 2:
I have just noticed that the display is actually on, it is just extremely dim, if I put a window with a white background on it then I can tell there is something there but it is too dim to see.

Look into your bios to activate intels integratd graphics.

I've gone into the UEFI firmware section and can't see any options for graphics in there. Is there a separate way to get into BIOS? I tried F11 F12 and delete but didn't get anywhere. Thanks

computer modell and brand? If you do not know Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/386927/how-to-know-the-model-of-the-computer-from-ubuntu make sure you have no gedit running before executing gedit file

I have added the output to the question

You have a Medion Erazer P10 try here last post https://community.medion.com/t5/Desktop-PC-All-In-One/How-to-I-get-into-bios-Medion-Erazer-P10/td-p/116152

be careful, do not change anything if you do not know, get a friend who knows to help ypu.

I have tried all of the options in that post, F11 goes to some HDD recovery, F12 does nothing and Delete does nothing. F2 goes to UEFI and I can't see any options to do with graphics hardware.

Well sorry that is as far as I can help

Okay, thanks for your time Amar.
